# Why is Haversine not working for me with large dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, latitude-longitude, haversine

I am trying to find the nearest underground station given a point using the Haversine formula implementation in Python, but I get a KeyError, which i think means that the key is not in the dictionaries. However, when i reduce the data to a minimal size, the Haversine formula works.

I don't understand what I need to do so I can make it work with larger dataset. Here is my code for Haversine formula:

```
def dist_between_two_lat_lon(*args):
    from math import asin, cos, radians, sin, sqrt
    lat1, lat2, long1, long2= map(radians, args)
    dist_lats= abs(lat2-lat1) 
    dist_longs= abs(long2-long1)
    a= sin(dist_lats/2)**2+ cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dist_longs/2)**2
    c= asin(sqrt(a)) * 2
    radius_earth= 6378
  
    return c* radius_earth

def find_closest_lat_lon(data, v):
    try:
        return min(data, key=lambda p: dist_between_two_lat_lon(v['lat'],p['lat'],v['lon'],p['lon']))
    except TypeError:
        print('Not a list or not a number.')
```

and my dataset:

```
ActonTown= {'lat': 51.5028, 'lon': -0.2801, 'name': 'Acton Town'}
Aldgate= {'lat': 51.5143, 'lon': -0.0755, 'name': 'Aldgate'}
AldgateEast= {'lat': 51.5154, 'lon': -0.0726, 'name': 'Aldgate East'}
AllSaints= {'lat': 51.5107, 'lon': -0.013, 'name': 'All Saints'}
Alperton= {'lat': 51.5407, 'lon': -0.2997, 'name': 'Alperton'}
Angel= {'lat': 51.5322, 'lon': -0.1058, 'name': 'Angel'}
.......
......
......
......



station_list =[ActonTown, Aldgate, AldgateEast, Alperton, Angel.....]


stationToFind= {'lat': 
51.5886014, 'lon': -0.1059771} 
print(find_closest_lat_lon(station_list, stationToFind))
```

Here is the error I get:

```
return min(data, key=lambda p: dist_between_two_lat_lon(v['lat'],p['lat'],v['lon'],p['lon']))KeyError: 'lon'
```

I tried to change the parts of the code so it can work for a larger dataset, it worked, however, it was not accurate.

What do i need to do in order to make the Haversine formula work with a large dataset?

Best,
Sakir